# Mobile Connect Contacts to Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

What is the best way to add or update contacts, who opt in through Mobile Connect, to Salesforce. Want to see if they have an existing contact or create a contact

Comment: The best way would be to create a query to check against a synched DE to see if they exist and then use Bulk API for updates/creation: https://tidbitsforu.com/send-sfmc-sfdc-using-ssjs-bulkapi2/

Comment: What about on a continual basis?

Comment: This is the way to do it on continual basis, in Automation Studio